# How to stream Images from http into an CursomAdapter(Android)

Tags: android, imageview, adapter, bitmapfactory

I have an Android custom listview adapter,

I need to stream/load some images into my custom-row-layout/ImageView.

So I have try with:

> myImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(o.getIcon_url()));

Like this code below.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View v = convertView;
       if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_applications, null);
       }
       ApplicationsModel o = items.get(position);
       if (o != null) {
            ImageView tv_icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_icon);
            if(row_icon !=null)
            {              
                  tv_icon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(o.getIcon_url()));
            }
       }
       return v;
}
```

But the images do not reader in my custom-listview.

The code works with TextView´s..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imageLoader.DisplayImage("URL_you_image", YOUimageIcon);

hm i am use this source https://github.com/thest1/LazyList works well, loads images asynchronously;)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like @Max_Usanin has the right answer here. I am leaving another answer to explain why it is not working now.

You need to download the images before you use them in `BitmapFactory`. The method you are using can only be used for local files, not url's. [See this link.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29)

Also, you really want to download the image asynchronously, which it appears `LazyList` does. It would be way too risky and possibly too long of a time to wait for each bitmap to download before you load another one into your `ListView`.